# How to switch flutter plugin architecture from arm64 to armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

When I tried to decrease my flutter app's deployment target (iOS 12 to 9.3), I received this error when running `flutter build ios`:

```
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    fatal error: lipo: -extract armv7 specified but fat file:
    /Users/xxx/development/myapp/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/flutter_webview_plugin.framework/flutter_webview_plugin does not contain that architecture
    Failed to extract armv7 for /Users/xxx/development/myapp/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/flutter_webview_plugin.framework/flutter_webview_plugin. Running
    lipo -info:
    Architectures in the fat file: /Users/xxx/development/myapp/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/flutter_webview_plugin.framework/flutter_webview_plugin are:
    arm64
```

I am unable to find any information on how to change the architecture in question - can I even do this? Or is this something the plugin developer has to build in?

I would like to be able to run the app with the lowest possible iOS version for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

In the project build settings, there is a section called Architectures, there you can set the ones you need. As far as I know, the latest iPhones need to use arm64, but in my picture you can see that I'm also set as valid armv7, that seems to be your problem.

[image]

Comment: This setting already looks exactly like it does on your machine.
Weirdly enough, I am able to build, archive and run the app without problems from XCode - it is just on the command line where I get the error message described above...